# Multi stage form on one page using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm attempting to create a form where the user is presented with a drop down list of options (the list will be to select a department in a company) and then once they have made their selection and hit submit, on the same page appears a new drop down list to select the member of staff. Those members of staff will only belong to the department that was selected. Once they have selected the member of staff and hit submit a new page can open with that member of staffs details.

The area I'm stuck on is how to make that second selection appear on the same page after the first selection has been done.

Here's the code I'm working with. This gets me my first drop down list where it pulls the list of departments from the relevant database table and populates the the drop-down. I need help with what to make the submit button do to get the next drop-down list:

```
<form action="<WHAT DO I PUT HERE?>" method="post">
    <Name='deptselect'>
    <select name="deptselect">
        <?php
        $SQL="SELECT name_of_dept FROM department where ID >= '1'";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        while ($sqlrow=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $sqldept=$sqlrow["name_of_dept"];
            echo "<option>
                  $sqldept
                  </option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: If you are submitting to the same page, you can leave the `action` attribute off completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML5, you can leave the `action` attribute off the `form` element and it will submit to the same page.

As for handling which step your user is in, probably recommend using a hidden form element tracking the actions. Something like this:

```
<form>
    <!-- All other form data here -->
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="1">
</form>
```

Then you can just logically figure out/update the status as the user moves through the steps. Perhaps a simple `switch` statement to display appropriate drop down. Maybe like this:

```
switch ($_POST['status']) {
   case 1: // Step 1 of the form
       break;
   case 2: // Step 2 of the form...and so on
       break;
}
```